# Normalvector for Quad

Tags: opengl, vector, normals

I've drawn a simple quad with glBegin and glEnd. With a for-loop I create copies of the quad and rotate it around my y-Axis in 3D space.
Now the problem is that I only see the quads in the front. These in the back are not displayed. I assume that the problem lies within the normal vector, which direction is towards me. Is there a possibility to define two normal vectors for one quad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to disable backface culling:

```
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Answer (score 0):

> These in the back are not displayed. I assume that th problem lies within the normal-vector,

The problem is not the normal vector, but what OpenGL considers front side and backside. What's what is determined by the winding of the vertices on the screen. If the vertices are on screen in counterclockwise order, then by default OpenGL assumes the front face. If back face culling is enables, back faces will not be drawn. You can disable culling, but then you'll get odd lighting results.

The best way is to draw the back side explicitly with it's own set of quads; windings and normals adjusted.